# How to set up orientation in manifest for tablets as landscape and portrait for phones?

Tags: android

How to set up orientation in manifest for tablets as landscape and portrait for phones?

I want:

```
    <application 
            android:name=".App"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:installLocation="preferExternal"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:largeHeap="true"

            <!--for phones-->
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            <!--for tablets-->
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
....
```

In one manifest. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it's not possible , you have to check that on runtime .

Check if it's Tablet by :

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context context)
{
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}
```

and then in your Activity, set orientation like this before **setContentView()**

```
if(isTablet(this))
{
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); 
}
else
{
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check at run time by calling below method:

```
boolean isTablet(Context context) {
        boolean isTablet = false;
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getApplicationContext().getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics();
        Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService("window"))
                .getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        int height = display.getHeight();

        float density = metrics.density;
        if ((width / density >= 600.0F) && (height / density >= 600.0F))
            isTablet = true;
        else {
            isTablet = false;
        }

        return isTablet;
    }
```

and you can set by orientation by calling in onCreate method

```
if(isTablet(this)
     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); 
 else
     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```